# Find roots of $\sum_i \alpha_i\,\cos(\beta_i\,t)$

Tags: roots

I'd like to solve *analytically* the following equation, where $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ have known values in $\mathbb{R}$:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i\leqslant N} \alpha_i\,\cos(\beta_i\,t)=0
\end{equation}

Would there be an exact solution to this problem?

Mathematica only finds approximated solutions, which prevents me from calculating the null space of the matrix whose determinant is the left-hand side of the above equation.

Comment: Probably no analytical solution unless you have some specific $\alpha$s and $\beta$s.

Comment: @YuliaV That's my intuition too but do you have reasons do think so?

Comment: intuition - it is like a polynom, but more general, and there are no general solutions for polynoms for the degree greater than 4. No proof, analytical solution is like guilt; you presume that there is none unless shown otherwise.

Comment: This is possibly only if your $\alpha_,\beta_i$ are "nice." Do you have exact expressions for them?

Comment: @AlexR. Unfortunately not: they correspond to physical properties (masses & stiffnesses). I'll have to cope with the fact that there is no general solution...